# Possible to pipe within python -c

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I want to do an `ls` command and then use python's `re` library to filter the results, the equivalent of this

```
$ ls|grep c
cmd.py
```

Is this possible to do across pipes? For example, something like this:

```
$ ls|python -c "import re,sys;r=re.search('^c', sys.argv[0]); print (r.group(1))"
                                                   ^
                                            #   'pretending' the output of `ls` is passed in sys.argv
```

Is this possible to do without a lot of legwork (such as reading/writing to a file)?

Comment: Use `sys.stdin` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin

Comment: `sys.argv` is command line arguments, not input.

Comment: @flakes cool that worked, thanks for the suggestion (put in the answer below).

Comment: The *question* [here](/questions/7091413/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python-from-a-pipe-which-has-no-ending) seems to answer your question.

Comment: **Don't filter `ls`.** It's fundamentally unreliable. Python already has `os.listdir` - use that instead.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica right, the above example is just made up. I'm just using this as what I thought would be the most basic way of showing how to do a pipe from a cmd to python.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel not really, I want to limit everything to the command line and a very terse one-liner, though I understand the duplicate discusses reading from stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From *@flakes* comment you can use [`stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) to get the input data. For example:

```
$ ls|python -c "import re,sys;r=re.search(r'c.+', sys.stdin.read()); print (r.group())"
# cmd.py
```

Comment: No need to use a raw string `r''` there. You're not using any escaped characters in the regex. i.e backslashes

Comment: @flakes It's a good habit to always use a raw string for regexp. There's no harm if it doesn't contain any escape sequences.

Comment: @flakes -- thanks, at this point it's really just a habit and whenever I write a regex I use it (my editor even highlights the regex text different than a normal string). Is there any downside for using it though when no escapes are needed?

Comment: @Barmar that's fair, seems reasonable enough. I usually opt to use the least amount of features required by the code. (e.g. flake8 now will yell at you if you use an f-string `f""` without any formats `{...}` used). Is there any PEP around that rule?